# css list odd even classes

Tags: css, css-float, css-selectors

Can anyone please help me about my problem. I'm trying to create separate style for odd and even list elements using css. the even code works perfect but odd code doesn't please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.

```
#entries-content.list ul.col-1 li:nth-child(odd) .time { 
    position:absolute;
    width:19px;
    height:21px;
    background-image:url(images/arrow.png);
    background-position:-20px -21px;
    float:right 
}


#entries-content.list ul.col-1 li:nth-child(even) .time { 
    position:absolute;
    margin:20px 0 0 -15px;
    width:19px;
    height:21px;
    background-image:url(images/arrow.png);
    background-position: 0px -21px; 
    float:left;
}
```

The odd list item doesn't float to right side also the width and height are not working. The even code is working perfectly.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Why are you styling odd _and_ even? Wouldn't it be easier to style the default (aka, both) with one and then just override background with a specific even style? This way you even save yourself the hassle of defining width and height twice, easier to modify later even.

Comment: Why are you absolutely positioning floats?

Comment: I've tested at both chrome and firefox here is what I'm trying to do http://i.imgur.com/jHoMX.jpg the left side arrow don't appear. also I want to change colors of odd and even list elements, thats why Im using it

Answer (score 3):

`position:absolute` will remove your element from the flow of their parent element. Using `float: value` on those elements will result in [no float applied](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position):

> [...] This property specifies whether a box should float to the left, right, or not at all. It may be set for any element, but only applies to elements that generate boxes **that are not absolutely positioned**. [...]

Since you don't use any positioning value (`top`,`left`,`right`,`bottom`) I assume you can just remove `position:absolute`.

Comment: It's not undefined behavior. Absolutely-positioned elements will simply [not float](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo).

Comment: Please check the result of above code http://i.imgur.com/7d0ds.jpg I've tested by removing position:absolute; but it doesn't work. I guess the browser don't support odd and even elements very well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem, but there is a semicolon missing:

```
background-image:url(images/arrow.png);background-position:-20px -21px;float:right; }
```

Edit: You could use right and left instead of float, since you use `position: absolute`.

Note: you have to use `position: absolute` or `relative` at the parent div, because otherwise it might be that left and right does not have the effect you want it to have.

```css
#entries-content.list ul.col-1 li:nth-child(odd) .time { 
    position:absolute;
    width:19px;
    height:21px;
    background-image:url(images/arrow.png);
    background-position:-20px -21px;
    right: 0px;
}


#entries-content.list ul.col-1 li:nth-child(even) .time { 
    position:absolute;
    margin:20px 0 0 -15px;
    width:19px;
    height:21px;
    background-image:url(images/arrow.png);
    background-position: 0px -21px; 
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: The last rule in a group of rules doesn't need a semicolon.

Comment: I think semicolon doesn't effect at the end of the lines, also minifying will remove all of semicolons at the end of the lines

Comment: @Alex Schimp please check this image. now both arrows are appearing. #entries-content.list ul.col-1 li:nth-child(odd) {  float:left; }
#entries-content.list ul.col-1 li:nth-child(even) {  float:right}​
I've removed both and added position:relative instead of absolute in odd element now both columns have collapsed. can you please guide me what do I do now to make space between both of them? if I use margin-left it will apply at all <li> items